# Как реализовать поиск по категории?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, есть такие модели:

Модель с фильмом(кино-сеанс)

```
class FilmSession < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :film_session_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :film_session_categories
end
```

модель категории категории

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :film_session_categories
  has_many :film_sessions, through: :film_session_categories

  has_many :search_categories
  has_many :searches, through: :search_categories
end
```

Модель поиска

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :search_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :search_categories

  def search_film_sessions

    film_sessions = FilmSession.all
    film_sessions = film_sessions.where(["session_name LIKE ?","%#{keywords}%"]) if keywords.present?
    film_sessions = film_sessions.where(["rating >= ?", rating]) if rating.present?

    return film_sessions
  end
end
```

Контроллер поиска

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @search = Search.new
  end

  def create
    @search = Search.create(search_params)
    redirect_to @search
  end

  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
  end


  private

    def search_params
       params.require(:search).permit(:keywords, :max_price, :rating, category_ids: [])
     end
 end
```

И форма для поиска :

```
<div class="well bs-component text-center">
  <h1>Advanced search</h1>

 <%= form_for @search, html: {class: "pure-form"} do |f| %>

 <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">

    <div class="form-group is-empty">
       <label class="col-md-2 control-label text-danger">Keywords</label>
       <div class="col-md-10">
         <%= f.text_field :keywords, class:"form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group is-empty">
       <label class="col-md-2 control-label text-danger">Min rating</label>
       <div class="col-md-10">
         <%= f.number_field :rating, class:"form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-8 mt20">
        <%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name do |cd| %>
          <%= cd.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") { cd.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cd.text } %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-0">
       <%= link_to 'Back', film_sessions_path, class:"btn btn-raised btn-default" %>
       <%= f.submit class:"btn btn-raised btn-primary m20" %>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <% end %>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что не могу понять, как пройтись по двум массивам с категориями (category_ids: []) в Search и FilmSession, сравнить там значения, и записать в переменную film_sessions те сеансы, которые относятся к той категории, поиск по которой мы проводим.
Для лучшей наглядности добавлю скриншот с поиском :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что у вас за реализация поиска?

Comment: Отсюда https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUtUquKc2qQ

Comment: Оооой, ад какой. Выкиньте этот видеоурок подальше. Отвратительный код и практики: сохранение в БД чего-то, что и так получается от пользователя каждый раз, возможности шаблона используются скудно. А по вашему вопросу: без JS дело не обойдётся, если для разных значений одного списка должны быть разные значения другого.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за совет)